# How to handle multiple language translations in one app?

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm writing app using JavaFX. I want to use one language for user interface and another for documentation handling in that app. I will give user a choice which languages to use for documentation and which one for interface. Currently I'm using `lang_en.properties` file with `ResourceBundle`. If I will need in the same window to display interface in english from `lang_en.properties` and some generated fields with text from `lang_de.properties` how can I do that?